# Does there exist a simple graph with the degree sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Does there exist a simple graph with 7 vertices and the degree sequence {0,2,2,2,3,5,6}?

I know that the Handshaking Lemma says that the sum of the degrees is twice the number of edges. In this case the number of edges is 20, which means that the graph must exist. However, the part I'm iffy about is can a simple graph have a vertex with degree zero?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Vertex number $7$ has degree $6$, which means it must be joined to every other vertex.  But...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If you have a simple graph with $7$ vertices, and one has degree $6$, what does this mean?

Comment: In a simple graph, you can't have a degree 6 vertex when my only options for connecting that vertex are 5 other vertices. So the simple graph for the sequence doesn't exist?

Comment: @user132909 Yes.